# i am writing a tic tac toe game and adding click events for input of X or O but after input i want to remove click event

Tags: javascript

i am writing a tic tac toe game and adding click events for input of X or O but after input i want to remove click event. i am not able to remove click events from box insted it is getting multiplied after each click. any help would be appericiated

```
const option = document.querySelectorAll(".option")
const options = document.querySelector(".options")
const boxes = document.querySelector(".boxes")
const box =document.querySelectorAll('.box')
const turn = document.querySelector(".turn")

option.forEach(item =>{
    item.addEventListener('click',function(){
        turn.classList.add("hidden")
        boxes.classList.remove('hidden')
        takeTurn(item.id)
        
    })
})

function takeTurn(selection){
  box.forEach(selected => {
      selected.addEventListener('click' , function(){
          console.log(selected)
          if(selection === "X"){
              selected.innerHTML = "<span>X</span>"
              nextTurn("O")
              unClick()
              
          }else{
              selected.innerHTML = "<span>O</span>"
              nextTurn("X")
              unClick()
             
          }
      })
  })
}

function nextTurn(value){
    if(value === "X"){
        takeTurn("X")
    }else{
        takeTurn("O")
    }
}

function unClick() {
    box.forEach(selected => {
        selected.removeEventListener('click', takeTurn)
    })
}
```

Comment: Because `takeTurn()` is not the function that was bound as the event callback (an anonymous function was), so trying to unbind it will do nothing. This would be a very good time to learn about [event delegation](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-event-delegation#event-delegation-less-code), which avoids this sort of multi-element event binding and having to bind/unbind.

Comment: if i change it to something like function(){ console.log("xyz")} @Mitya

Comment: @Teemu Oops, that's embarassing - thanks very much for spotting and letting me know about it.

Comment: also there's a logical error.. every `takeTurn`, *EVERY* child of `box` gets a new event listener

Comment: @The Bomb Squad  I am trying to call a function to remove event in takeTurn

Comment: As I mentioned previously, you're trying to unbind the *wrong* function - one that was never bound in the first place. Binding/unbinding in this way is tricky because it's not straightforward to unbind an anonymous function. Event delegation pretty much solves all of this, if you're willing to learn and do some refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't removing AN event, it would be removing a whole set of events PER selection since each selection gets/**gains** an event listener each turn

I just moved around that logical stranglehold to make ur tictactoe game work

Are there new errors? Please tell me the results

```
const option = document.querySelectorAll(".option")
const options = document.querySelector(".options")
const boxes = document.querySelector(".boxes")
const box =document.querySelectorAll('.box')
const turn = document.querySelector(".turn")
let selection="X" //it can start off as "O" too
let nextSelection={"X":"O", "O":"X"} //less lines than an if/else statement

option.forEach(item =>{
    item.addEventListener('click',function(){
        turn.classList.add("hidden")
        boxes.classList.remove('hidden')
        
    })
})


box.forEach(selected => {
    function listener(){
        selected.innerHTML = `<span>${selection}</span>`
        selection=nextSelection[selection]
        selected.removeEventListener('click', listener)
    }
    selected.addEventListener('click' , listener)
})
```